Automatically Add Woocommerce Attributes in Dokan
I have written a code that automatically adds all of the product attributes when adding a new auction product in the Dokan Multivendor plugin for Woocommerce. The problem is when I save the product, the attribute terms are mapped to a single random attribute.
This is the code snippet that I use:
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'dokan_auto_add_auction_attributes_dynamic', 99 );
function dokan_auto_add_auction_attributes_dynamic() {
    // Check if we are on the auction creation or edit page by inspecting the URL parameters
    if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' && isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) ) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // List of predefined attributes to add automatically for auctions
            var predefinedAttributes = [
                'pa_box',
                'pa_brand',
                'pa_case-size',
                'pa_condition',
                'pa_dial-color',
                'pa_material',
                'pa_papers',
                'pa_reference-number',
                'pa_watch-year'
            ];

            // Function to add attributes automatically
            function addAttributes() {
                predefinedAttributes.forEach(function(attribute) {
                    // Set the predefined attribute in the select dropdown
                    $('#predefined_attribute').val(attribute).change();

                    // Simulate clicking the "Add Attribute" button
                    $('.add_new_attribute').trigger('click');
                });
            }

            // Trigger the function after the page has fully loaded
            setTimeout(addAttributes, 0); // Adjust delay as necessary
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

How can I ensure that the terms (it should be a single one per attribute) is mapped and saved to the correct attribute after saving the product?
